# Room не добавляет элемент

Tags: android, kotlin, room, moxy

Не могу понять в чем проблема. Добавляю элемент в базу, все добавляется без ошибок, но при получении списка из базы он пуст. Использую Room и Moxy
addPersonPresenter:

```
class AddPersonPresenter(application: Application): MvpPresenter<AddPersonView>() {

    private val repository = MyRepository.getInstance(application)

    fun startActivity() {
        viewState.showActivity()
    }

    fun addPerson(person: Person) {
        Log.d("M_AddPersonPresenter","addPerson")
        presenterScope.launch { repository.insertPerson(person)}
    }
}
```

MyRepository:

```
class MyRepository(applicationContext: Application) {

    private lateinit var personDao: PersonDao
    private lateinit var eventDao: EventDao
    companion object{
        @Volatile private var INSTANCE : MyRepository? = null

    fun getInstance(applicationContext: Application): MyRepository? {
            if (INSTANCE == null) {
                synchronized(MyRepository::class) {
                    INSTANCE = MyRepository(applicationContext)
                }
            }
            return INSTANCE
        }
    }
    init {

    init {
        val database = MyDatabase.getInstance(applicationContext)
        personDao = database!!.personDao()
        eventDao = database.eventDao()
    }

    //Person
    fun getAllPerson():LiveData<List<Person>> = personDao.getAllPerson()

    suspend fun deletePerson(person: Person) = withContext(Dispatchers.IO){personDao.deletePerson(person)}

    suspend fun updatePerson(person: Person) = withContext(Dispatchers.IO){personDao.updatePerson(person)}

    suspend fun insertPerson(person: Person) {

        withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
            Log.d("M_MyRepository","insert person $person")
            personDao.insertPerson(person)
        }
    }

    //Event

    fun getAllEvent():LiveData<List<Event>> = eventDao.getAllEvents()

    suspend fun deleteEvent(event: Event) = withContext(Dispatchers.IO){eventDao.deleteEvent(event)}

    suspend fun updateEvent(event: Event) = withContext(Dispatchers.IO){eventDao.updateEvent(event)}

    suspend fun insertEvent(event: Event) = withContext(Dispatchers.IO){eventDao.insertEvent()}

}
```

PersonDao:

```
@Dao
interface PersonDao {

    @Query("SELECT * FROM person ORDER BY name")
    fun getAllPerson(): LiveData<List<Person>>

    @Insert
    fun insertPerson(vararg person: Person)

    @Delete
    fun deletePerson(person: Person)

    @Update
    fun updatePerson(person: Person)
}
```

Entity:

```
@Entity
data class Person(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    val id: Int?,
    val name: String,
    val dob: Int,
    val height: Int,
    val weight: Int
)
```

PersonPresenter:

```
class PersonPresenter(application: Application): MvpPresenter<PersonView>() {

    private val repository = MyRepository.getInstance(application)
    val list = repository.getAllPerson()

    fun onStartFragment() {

        if (list.value.isNullOrEmpty()) {
            Log.d("M_PersonPresenter","list empty")
        } else {
            Log.d("M_PersonPresenter","showPerson")
        viewState.showPersonList(list.value!!)
        }
    }
}
```

После добавления Person получаем следующие логи:

```
M_AddPersonPresenter: addPerson
M_AddPersonActivity: addPerson
M_MyRepository: insert person Person(id=null, name=Иванов, dob=2010, height=150, weight=50)
M_PersonPresenter: list empty
```

Не могу понять почему список пустой вставка же прошла.

Comment: Не ясно как вы убедились, что что-то действительно вставилось. У вас лишь вывод в логи перед попыткой вставки. Также не ясно в какой последовательности вы код ваш вызываете. Возможно вы запрашиваете выборку из БД до того, как в неё что-то запишите. Помимо этого сказать нечего - в целом в коде ошибок не видно.

Comment: Я многого еще не понимаю, поэтому и столько вопросов. Как я могу проверить прошла ли вставка или нет? У меня открывается активити, там я заношу данные и отправлю их в addPersonPresenter.addPerson(person), затем в addPersonPresentor делаем repository.insertPerson(person), далее personDao.insertPerson(person), ну и затем мы закрываем активити и возвращаемся в фрагмент (где по идее должен быть список), фрагмент через свой презентор проверяет list и если он не пустой выполняет функцию показа списка. Мне кажется у меня какая-то проблема именно с получением списка.

Comment: Мне кажется, что проблема здесь: `закрываем активити и возвращаемся в фрагмент` - вы уверены, что после возврата на фрагмент (как происходит возврат?) вы не перезапрашиваете данные в БД и вам отображается старая выборка, в которой ничего нет. Проверьте для начала, что у вас что-то вставилось, вызвав код для выборки сразу после вставки.

Comment: В репозитории изменил suspend fun insertPerson(person: Person) {
        withContext(Dispatchers.IO){
            Log.d("M_MyRepository","insert person $person")
            personDao.insertPerson(person)            Log.d("M_MyRepository","${personDao.getAllPerson().value.isNullOrEmpty()}")}
    } И он мне выдал true, значит туда ничего не добавилось или getAllPerson работает не корректно

Comment: Все-таки он скорее всего добавляет в таблицу, так как когда я я ставил id null (для автоинкремента) он мне давал несколько раз нажать кнопку добавить, а когда я жестко указал Id = 1 то при втором добавлении упал.

Comment: У вас слишком много мест где может быть неправильно. Вам надо как-то локализовать проблему. Например убедиться, что данные реально записываются в БД. Хотя бы вытащив её из памяти эмулятора и открыв программой для просмотра, если вы таки уверены, что данные записываются. Если они запиываются - пробуйте другие способы получения данных. Я лично ни с корутинами ни с LiveData много времени не возился - не могу сказать что там может быть не так. Видно только, что вы, кажется, пытались сделать синглтон для репозитория, но это у вас явно не вышло - присвоения значения нигде не происходит.